# How to Make Sequential API Calls and Merge the Results In Spring Boot Webflux

Tags: java, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I already have a reactive stream that does the following :

1.Retrieve a list of object Ids by calling another REST API

2.Retrieve a list of events for each object id by calling another REST API

3.Return a Mono list combining both of above responses

My new requirement is to integrate another web request which have to use the above combined response from two API calls.
So new call will have to use existing data to build the request body.
My problem is whether its possible to do this in the same reactive stream? Or do I have to block the current implementation and get the response and then execute the new web call?

Current implementation :

```
public Mono<List<ObjectInfo>> getEventsForReference(String reference, Postcode postcode) {
    return connector.resolveForExternalReference(reference)
        .flatMapIterable(ResolvedObjectIds::getIds)
        .flatMap(id -> getEventsFor(id)
            .map(parcel -> redact(parcel, id, postcode)))
        .collectList()
        .doOnError(throwable -> log.error(SERVICE_ERROR, throwable.getMessage()));
}

private Mono<ParcelInfo> getEventsFor(ResolvedObjectId id) {
    return gateway.getObjectBy(uid).zipWith(gateway.getEventsBy(uid)) //
            .map(tuple -> combineEvents(tuple.getT1(), tuple.getT2()));
}

private ObjectInfo redact(ObjectInfo obj, ResolvedObjectId id, Postcode postcode) {
    boolean fullResponse = ResolvedObjectId.isReturn(obj.getBarcode()) || uid.isReturn() || obj.hasPostcode(postcode);
    return fullResponse ? parcel : redact(parcel);
}
```

New web request i'm trying to integrate with above :

```
  public Mono<AvailableResponse> getAvailableDiversionsForObject(final int objectId, 
                            final EventsRequest eventsRequest) {
    return webclient
        .method(HttpMethod.GET)
        .uri("available/{objectId}", objectId)
        .body(Mono.just(eventsRequest), EventsRequest .class)
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .retrieve()
        .onStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND::equals, r -> Mono.empty())
        .onStatus(HttpStatus::isError, response -> Mono.error(WebClientResponseException.create(
                      response.statusCode().value(),
                      response.statusCode().getReasonPhrase(),
                      response.headers().asHttpHeaders(),
                      null,
                      null
                  ))
        )
        .bodyToMono(AvailableResponse.class)
        .doOnError(throwable -> log.error(SERVICE_ERROR, throwable.getMessage()));
}
```

`EventsRequest` should be populated by the current response of `resolveForExternalReference` which is the first API call. And then altogether both calls' responses should be merged making `availableDiversions` set to `Mono<ObjectInfo>`.

ObjectInfo class :

```
@Builder
@Data
public class ObjectInfo {

 private String barcode;
 private List<String> availableDiversions;

}
```

AvailableResponse class :

```
@Builder
@Data
public class AvailableResponse{

 private List<String> availableDiversions;

}
```